# Display members of a group with picture and a facility to add a new user(in case Admin/Owner) and viewable for any other groups or users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

[image: Display the group members profile with photos]

Hi all,

I need to display the group members as shown in the Image.Is there any out of box method to implement this. I am using sharepoint 2010. In case of Admin/Owner, they should have an option to add a new member to the group, while all other sharepoint groups and users need to have view permission only. How to implement this in case we are using Visual studio 2010 visual webparts. Any help is welcomed.

Thanks and Regards
Jijesh